# Expression involving a power of 1.5

Tags: roots, index-notation

How do you simplify

**u<sup>1.5</sup>**

in root form?

<sup>0.5</sup> is the root of **u** but im confused with **1**.5

Please help

Thankyou

Comment: $u^{1.5}=u^{1 + 0.5}=u^{1}u^{0.5}$ if it helps.

Comment: I thought so too, thanks

Comment: @Atbey you should post your comment as an answer imho :)

Comment: @user477343 It was a comment to the first question, so I will leave it as if no one mind :)

Comment: @LianaA No problem

Comment: @LianaA Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$u^{1.5}=u^{\frac{3}{2}}=\sqrt{u^3}=|u|\sqrt{u}$$

Comment: we can write simply $u\sqrt{u}$ since the expression is defined for $u\ge 0$

Answer (score 2):

In general for $a,b$ positive integer

$$u^{\frac a b}= \sqrt[b]{u^a}$$